# Word COM Object loop - faulting over time

Tags: powershell

I have a script that goes through a list of CSV files, each with 100 entries. Basically, it creates a word document based on the data in that line, here is the start of the loop:

```
while ( ( Get-Childitem "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\DataFiles-new\").count -ne 0 ) {
    [int]$hour = get-date -format HH

    If ( $hour -gt 6 -and $hour -lt 6 ) {
        Start-Sleep -s 1800100}
    else {
        foreach ( $file in ( Get-Childitem "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\DataFiles-new\" ) ) {
            # Connect Word
            $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
            $objWord.Visible = $false 

            $templatedir = "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\Templates\Resumes\Out\"

            $templateDir = Get-ChildItem ("\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\Templates\Resumes\Out\") | Get-Random -Count 1 
            $templateFile = $templateDir
            $templateDir =  ("\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\Templates\Resumes\Out\" + $templateDir)

            if (!(checkLock $file.fullname) -and (Test-Path $file.FullName) ) {
                $cand_CSV = Import-CSV $file.fullname

                $LockFile = [System.io.File]::Open("$($file.fullname)", 'Open', 'Read','None')
                Write-Host "[+] Processing file $($file.fullname)" -foregroundcolor GREEN

                foreach ( $line in $cand_CSV ) {
```

here is the end:

```
                }

                $LockFile.Close()
                Remove-Item $file.fullname -force
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "$($file.fullname) :: locked - continuing"
            }

            $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$objWord)
            [gc]::Collect()
            [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            Remove-Variable objWord 

        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the foreach loop is just adding data to bookmarks in Word.

Basically, I am trying to create around 1,000,000 spoof resumes, which is taking too long on just one PC so I want to be able to just have this run on a few PC's and leave it, the problem is, after a test run last night i noticed that there were about 150 WINWORD.EXE processes open and the computer had to be restarted.

One of the other PC's had a saveas box open which had prevented the script from continuing.

Shouldn't the following close down the Word process?

```
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$objWord)
            [gc]::Collect()
            [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            Remove-Variable objWord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop closing Word and relaunching it! Move the part where you create your Word comobject to before your loop. Close documents, but not Word. After the loop is done close Word and destroy the comobject.

```
# Connect Word
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false 
$templateRootDir = "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\Templates\Resumes\Out"

while ( ( Get-Childitem "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\DataFiles-new\").count -ne 0 ) {
    [int]$hour = get-date -format HH

    If ( $hour -gt 6 -and $hour -lt 6 ) { # Will NEVER happen. $hour can not be both greater than, and also less than 6.
        Start-Sleep -s 1800100}
    else {
        foreach ( $file in ( Get-Childitem "\\rspldata\QMS\Owain\Database-Anon-Resumes\DataFiles-new\" ) ) {
            $templateFile = Get-ChildItem $templateRootDir | Get-Random -Count 1
            $templateDir =  $templateFile.FullName

            if (!(checkLock $file.fullname) -and (Test-Path $file.FullName) ) {
                $cand_CSV = Import-CSV $file.fullname

                $LockFile = [System.io.File]::Open("$($file.fullname)", 'Open', 'Read','None')
                Write-Host "[+] Processing file $($file.fullname)" -foregroundcolor GREEN

                foreach ( $line in $cand_CSV ) {
                    $docResume = $objWord.Documents.add($templateDir)

                    <more code>

                    $docResume.Save()
                    $docResume.Close($false)
                }

                $LockFile.Close()
                Remove-Item $file.fullname -force
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "$($file.fullname) :: locked - continuing"
            }

        }
    }
}

$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$objWord)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
Remove-Variable objWord
```

Also, please see my comment after your first `If` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense, and yes I set the if statement to that for testing, forgot to change it back.

Comment: I'm not going to ask you how to do it because it is a completely separate question, but would it be easy / worthwhile to have it remove the line in the CSV file after it is processed? to make sure that nothing is missed.

Comment: You could do it, but it's going to cause a lot of overhead since you would have to rewrite the whole file minus one line each time, and I don't know how that'll work with your file locks. If your purpose is to keep track of progress it might be easier to append each completed line to a 'completed.csv' file (perhaps with an appended column to denote the originating file), and then only process records that aren't in the completed file.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good point, forgot about the lock. Your workaround will probably be the best approach, i will probably just recreate the file in a new folder (don't really want a 1000000 record CSV file ) and add a ~ or something in the filename to show that it hasn't been fully processed. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe removing the PowerShell variables is enough to get rid of the Word instances.  You have to explicitly tell Word to exit:

```
$objWord.quit()
```